# Problem with restart standalone RCp application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have problem with restarting RCP application. When I run under Eclipse everything is ok, but when I create standalone application method restart just close the applications. I use next code:
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
workbench.restart();
Is anybody know how to solve this.

THANKS

Answer (score 11):

This thread [is interesting](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg09969.html) in that regard (it explains why it works when the RCP is run from eclipse, and not when running standalone)

> If the workbench is restarted, e.g. via `IWorkbench.restart()`, that causes `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(...)` to return control to the application (the `IPlatformRunnable` implementation for the application extension) with a return code of `PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART` (value is 1).
>
> The application then must map this to an app return code of `IPlatformRunnable.EXIT_RESTART` (value is 23).
>
> This then becomes the exit code of the Java VM (i.e `System.exit(code)`).
>   **The `eclipse.exe` executable detects this special code, and relaunches the Java VM using the same command line arguments as the first time.**
>
> If you're not using `eclipse.exe` but are launching the java VM directly yourself, it won't restart automatically. You'll need to handle the exit code yourself.

So a code like that in your RCP will need to be amanged by some kind of launcher in order to interpret (and restart the rcp application if needed) the exist code.
(a bit like in this remote RCP management [wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Remote_Eclipse_RCP_Management))

```
WorkbenchAdvisor workbenchAdvisor = new CoreAppWorkbenchAdvisor();
Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
try {
  int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, workbenchAdvisor);
  if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART)
    return IPlatformRunnable.EXIT_RESTART;
  else
    return IPlatformRunnable.EXIT_OK;
  }
  finally {
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```